# Continue task on Virtual Machine when VirtualBox is minimized

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu on a VirtualBox Virtual Machine, and I'm downloading a large file on this virtual machine. This download would take more than 30 minutes, so I would like to minimize VirtualBox and continue working on my primary system. But when I minimize VirtualBox, then the virtual machine actually pauses and then the download also pauses. How can I make sure that VirtualBox doesn't pause my virtual machine when VirtualBox is minimized? I'm using VirtualBox 4.2.16.

Comment: I persoally don't have this problem.  You sure this isn't a setting you have enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't know whether there is a setting like that. That's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my VirtualBox from 4.2.16 to 4.3.6 solved my problem. Looks like this was an issue of VBox 4.2.16.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find, *there is no reason why this should happen*.

Check that whatever method you use for minimizing the window does not collide with another hotkey, button, method *or similar activity* that would result in the virtual machine being paused.